# Implement a UIAlertView when a UIWebView does not have an internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uialertview, reachability

I am creating a rather simple tab-based app with a few UIWebViews. To pass App Store Approval, I need to implement an error if there is no network connection. I'm a beginner, but I tried this and nothing happened.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

I've tried Reachability, but its complicated, and I'm not sure exactly how to implement it into a UIAlertView. Could this code work with tweaking or is it trash?

Comment: Turn off your network while the page in loading, it will show the alert..

Comment: Or first Turn off your network  and then run your App..

Comment: I have done that, ad no alert loads.

Comment: The timeout on webView:didFailLoadWithError: is fairly high, I believe it's around a minute or so. Did you wait that long?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_APLViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_APLViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6


Download this code.. and run to see how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Network Connection using Reachability Code at ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear ..Download them using below link

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

```
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus != NotReachable)
    {
     NSLog(@"Async.....Network is Available");
    }
    else
    {
 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"No Network Available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

Or You can Put alert on below delegate method of UIWebView

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: This works when it's just a WebView, but it doesn't work when the WebView is in a Tab.

Comment: It will work...Just put above code at ViewWillAppear of your view controller where you loading webview..!

Comment: I tried: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    Reachability *reach... etc. and it didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `delegate methods of webView` and implement it in ViewController.

There are mainly three delegate methods of webView.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

In didFailLoadWithError method you can identify error code using [error code]. You can use any of these as per your requirement.

```
// Error codes for CFURLConnection and CFURLProtocol
  kCFURLErrorUnknown = -998,
  kCFURLErrorCancelled = -999,
  kCFURLErrorBadURL = -1000,
  kCFURLErrorTimedOut = -1001,
  kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL = -1002,
  kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost = -1003,
  kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004,
  kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost = -1005,
  kCFURLErrorDNSLookupFailed = -1006,
  kCFURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects = -1007,
  kCFURLErrorResourceUnavailable = -1008,
  kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009,
```

These error codes are available in CFNetworkError.h. In my application i have used in this way.

```
 if ([error code] == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
        // if we can identify the error, we can present a more precise message to the user.
        UIAlertView *alertView=[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"Sorry, there doesn’t seem to be an internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]autorelease];
        [alertView show];
 }
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank for for this list of codes; it will help me out with the approach I want to take here. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

The viewcontroller which you have assigned delegate for the UIWebView; (in the code of viewcontroller where you have set the webview.delegate=self), you need to commit in the header (.h) file to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol. Only then your method :

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error

will be triggered. I guess you are missing this otherwise your process is correct.
So, add the UIWebViewDelegate in your .h file.

Hope this will help.